# Unexpected urls in my Jekyll website sitemap

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-theme

I'm creating my personal blog (davioooh.com) using Jekyll and hosting it on GitHub pages.

But I recently discovered a strange thing...

When pushed/deployed to my repository, the blog `sitemap.xml` includes two extra urls:

```
<url>
  <loc>
    http://davioooh.com/assets/javascript/anchor-js/docs/grunticon/preview.html
  </loc>
  <lastmod>2017-08-11T16:40:49+00:00</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>
    http://davioooh.com/assets/javascript/anchor-js/docs/index.html
  </loc>
  <lastmod>2017-08-11T16:40:49+00:00</lastmod>
</url>
```

I can't understand why... I'm not using any **anchor-js** gem or plug-in...

The only gems declared in my `_config.yml` and `Gemfile` are:

```
gems:
  - jekyll-feed
  - jekyll-seo-tag
  - jekyll-paginate
  - jekyll-sitemap
```

So why I'm getthing that urls?

**NOTE**: the sitemap is correct when I test the site locally on my dev machine.

**NOTE**: I'm using a custom theme (regular theme, not gem-based). No theme declared in my `_config.yml`. Here you find my blog repository: https://github.com/davioooh/davioooh.github.io

**UPDATE** Tried to replace `jekyll` gem with `github-pages` in my `Gemfile` as suggested by **marcanuy**. It works locally, but after a new push sitemap still includes the extra urls...

**UPDATE** Found GitHub pages [reference](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-jekyll/) listing default params for Jekyll websites. Default theme is, as expected, `jekyll-theme-primer`. How can I override this setting if I'm not using gem-based theme?

Comment: This is quite annoying, I can see that you've done the same thing and added `Disallow: /assets/javascript/*` to the sitemap to prevent search engines from indexing these pages

Comment: @SamDenty yes, I'm still looking for a solution... Meanwhile I applied this workaround...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that updating to github-pages **v157** the sitemap is generated correctly.

The [new version of gh-pages](https://github.com/github/pages-gem/releases/tag/v157) supports the last version of `jekyll-theme-primer` (v0.5.2).

This solves my issue.

Answer (score 2):

It comes from your theme: `jekyll-theme-primer`

Primer is what powers GitHub's frontend. If you're not using this theme explicitly, it probably comes from GitHub Pages' own usage of the Primer framework

Comment: I'm using a custom theme based on *minima* default theme. so how can I disable this?

Answer (score 2):

## Why it works fine locally?

Because you are not using the same dependencies Github Pages uses. To replicate the environment used by Github, you need to use the gem: `github-pages`.

## Why sitemap.xml includes two extra urls?

As @ashmaroli said, these files comes from `jekyll-theme-primer` which is used by Github Pages, if you are using your own theme files, then just make sure there are no `theme:` key in your `_config.yml` and run `bundle update`. Using the right `github-pages` gem will fix it and those files won't be included in your final site.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. I have no "theme" in my _config.yml and I replaced jekyll gem with github-pages, but after a new push sitemap still includes the extra url... what am I doing wrong? This is my site repository: https://github.com/davioooh/davioooh.github.io

Comment: I can't replicate the issue, it works fine locally and in http://davioooh.com/sitemap.xml they don't appear.

Comment: „Using the right github-pages gem will fix it and those files won't be included in your final site.“ – so how do I do that?

Comment: @FrankNocke step 2.2 here: https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-your-github-pages-site-locally-with-jekyll/

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Apparently, the jekyll-theme-primer (which usually comes with `group: :jekyll_plugins` in your `Gemfile`) is to blame. I.e.  `theme: minima` avoids the creation of `anchor-js` (but you probably want to run your own theme, and not having minima hang around…)

**2.** A verified simple fix (giving a warning upon build) is to write

```
theme: false
```

in your `_config.yml`

**3.** The issue [is **a known issue** and has been fixed 3 days before](https://github.com/github/pages-gem/issues/482#issuecomment-379934087) me writing this. Might day some days (or weeks) until it gets shipped though. If you read this some time from now, probably all you need to is update your gems.